# How do I use a function to plot two different data set?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm currently trying to plot two different graphs on the same svg. It's plane crashes (on the y-axis) in relation with the number of kms flown. I'm trying to put both the non-fatal crashes and the fatal crashes on the graph.
So far I just declared two classes of circles and plotted them, but I feel like I could do it more efficiently with a function.
So far I have this

```
    function myFunc(variable){
    count++;
    canevas.selectAll(`.c${count}`)
      .data(data)
      .enter
      .append("circle")
        .attr("class",`c${count}`)
        .attr("cx",d=>echelleKm(d.kmSemaine))
        .attr("cy",d=>echelleAccidents(d.variable))
        .attr("r",4)
        .attr("opacity",.5)
        .attr("fill",colors[count-1]);
  }
  myFunc(accidents85);
  myFunc(accidents00);
```

I get an error in the console saying `"(index):109 Uncaught ReferenceError: accidents85 is not defined"`, which I don't really get. If I do a `console.log(d3.max(data,d=>d.accidents85)` before the function is declared, I can see something in the console log.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm fairly new to d3.js and coding in general, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

edit : I put a picture of what the result should be if my function worked how I want it to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BsxC.png)

Comment: `d.accident85` is accessing a property of `d`, which is one of your data items - try `console.log(data[0].accident85)` instead

Comment: @thedude it gives me "undefined" when I got the console.log you suggested.

Comment: Can you share more of the code? Specifically where `accidents85` is defined

Comment: @thedude, sure here is how I did it :

`d3.csv("crash.csv",function(d){
        return{
         kmSemaine : +d.avail_seat_km_per_week,
         accidents85 : +d.incidents_85_99,
        };`

With some other variables declared, but I don't have the space to put them here. The thing is, my code works when I don't use a function.

edit : also, I'm sorry for the horrible formatting but I can't seem to use line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no variables called `accidents85` or `accidents00` defined anywhere. As you're just passing the property names of the objects inside your data array, you have to use quotes:

```
myFunc("accidents85");
myFunc("accidents00");
```

And then, inside your `myFunc`, use the bracket notation:

```
.attr("cy",d=>echelleAccidents(d[variable]))
```